# Override a method such as "#==" on every object in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Disclaimer: This is just to satisfy my curiosity – I have no plans on using this for anything. I realise this would rarely be a good idea!

I would love to hear any ideas for how this could be achieved, whether they're sensible or not so sensible.

How could I override a method such as `#==` on *every* object (`BasicObject`) in Ruby?

I could override it on `BasicObject`:

```
class BasicObject
  def ==(other); puts "custom for #{self} and #{other}!"; end
end
```

But this wouldn't work when a subclass also overrides it:

```
true == false  # Runs my custom code!
"a" == "b"  # Doesn't!

# Because of this:
true.method(:==)  # => #<Method: TrueClass(BasicObject)#==(_)>
"hi".method(:==)  # => #<Method: String#==(_)>
```

Prepending into `BasicObject` doesn't help, either – the subclass still wins – the prepended module is too far down the list:

```
String.ancestors  # => [String, Comparable, Object, Kernel, MyPrependedMod, BasicObject]
```

I could manually override it on `String` as well – but trying to do it manually on every class that overrides `#==` would be very error prone, especially since anyone could override it on some user-defined class at any time.

What are some ways of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution I came up with. To be clear, this is very likely not something you should add to a codebase. It's just for fun.

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Class) do |klass|
  next if klass.frozen?  # `Object` is frozen.

  klass.define_method(:==) { |other| puts "custom for #{self} and #{other}!" }
end

# These all work.
true == false
"a" == "b"
1 == 2
:hi == :bye
```

If you want to `prepend` (e.g. to call `super` in your override), there's a gotcha:

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Class) do |klass|
  next if klass.frozen?  # `Object` is frozen.

  # We can't use `prepend` here since e.g. `String` overrides it.
  # `prepend_features` is essentially the same thing.
  (Module.new do
    def ==(other); puts "custom for #{self} and #{other}!"; super; end
  end).send(:prepend_features, klass)
end

# These all work.
true == false
"a" == "b"
1 == 2
:hi == :bye
```

Instead of using `prepend_features`, we could alternatively make sure to call `BasicObject`'s `prepend` and not the one overridden in a subclass:

```
# Some classes, like `String`, override "prepend". 
prep = BasicObject.method(:prepend).unbind

ObjectSpace.each_object(Class) do |klass|
  next if klass.frozen?  # `Object` is frozen.

  prep.bind(klass).call(Module.new do
    def ==(other); puts "custom for #{self} and #{other}!"; super; end
  end)
end

# These all work.
true == false
"a" == "b"
1 == 2
:hi == :bye
```